# How to sort out numeric strings as numerics?

Tags: c#, .net, string, comparison

If you have strings like:

```
"file_0"
"file_1"
"file_2"
"file_3"
"file_4"
"file_5"
"file_6"
"file_11"
```

how can you sort them so that "file_11" doesn't come after "file_1", but comes after "file_6", since 11 > 6.

Do I have to parse the string and convert it into a number for this?

Windows explorer in Win7 sorts files out the way I wanted.

Comment: check also the alphanum algorithm: http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Comment: Thanks dfa, interesting indeed.

Comment: Here's a very good link.. http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/CSHARP/84_Sorting_in_Generic_List.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could import the [StrCmpLogicalW function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947.aspx) and use that to sort the strings. This is the very same function that Explorer itself uses for file names.

Won't help you if you don't want P/Invoke or stay compatible on other systems, though.

Answer (score 12):

> Do I have to parse the string and convert it into a number for this?

Essentially, yes; but LINQ may help:

```
var sorted = arr.OrderBy(s => int.Parse(s.Substring(5)));
foreach (string s in sorted) {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. It's certainly cleaner.

Comment: Btw Marc, is there a "till the end of string" to pass to a substring? Otherwise I need to do some calculations which will prevent me from using the dot notation, right?

Comment: The overload above *is* the "till the end of the string"... the 5 is the *start* index.

Answer (score 10):

To handle sorting of intermixed strings and numbers for any kind of format, you can use a class like this to split the strings into string and number components and compare them:

```
public class StringNum : IComparable<StringNum> {

   private List<string> _strings;
   private List<int> _numbers;

   public StringNum(string value) {
      _strings = new List<string>();
      _numbers = new List<int>();
      int pos = 0;
      bool number = false;
      while (pos < value.Length) {
         int len = 0;
         while (pos + len < value.Length && Char.IsDigit(value[pos+len]) == number) {
            len++;
         }
         if (number) {
            _numbers.Add(int.Parse(value.Substring(pos, len)));
         } else {
            _strings.Add(value.Substring(pos, len));
         }
         pos += len;
         number = !number;
      }
   }

   public int CompareTo(StringNum other) {
      int index = 0;
      while (index < _strings.Count && index < other._strings.Count) {
         int result = _strings[index].CompareTo(other._strings[index]);
         if (result != 0) return result;
         if (index < _numbers.Count && index < other._numbers.Count) {
            result = _numbers[index].CompareTo(other._numbers[index]);
            if (result != 0) return result;
         } else {
            return index == _numbers.Count && index == other._numbers.Count ? 0 : index == _numbers.Count ? -1 : 1;
         }
         index++;
      }
      return index == _strings.Count && index == other._strings.Count ? 0 : index == _strings.Count ? -1 : 1;
   }

}
```

Example:

```
List<string> items = new List<string> {
  "item_66b",
  "999",
  "item_5",
  "14",
  "file_14",
  "26",
  "file_2",
  "item_66a",
  "9",
  "file_10",
  "item_1",
  "file_1"
};

items.Sort((a,b)=>new StringNum(a).CompareTo(new StringNum(b)));

foreach (string s in items) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
9
14
26
999
file_1
file_2
file_10
file_14
item_1
item_5
item_66a
item_66b
```

Comment: @nawfal: If you call `Sort` without the comparer, it will use the default string comparison and you get a different result. Besides, the `List<T>` class did not exist prior to .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Guffa no, i meant one has to implement all what you wrote including interfacing like `public class StringNum : IComparable<StringNum>`. But the last line of code `items.Sort((a,b)=>new StringNum(a).CompareTo(new StringNum(b)));` wont work in .net 2.0 I suppose.. Or would it? I just used `items.Sort()` instead of it, and got the code working..!

Comment: @nawfal: The lambda expression won't work in C# 2.0, so you just write it using a delegate instead: `items.Sort(delegate(string a, string b){ return new StringNum(a).CompareTo(new StringNum(b)); });`.

Comment: @Guffa thanks for that.. But then how did using just `.Sort()` work for me? do u know why? When I merely tried to do `.Sort()` without any  `IComparable<StringNum>`, the code didnt even run; gave me an exception. See this linl, http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/CSHARP/84_Sorting_in_Generic_List.aspx It has `: IComparable<StringNum>` IComparable example in which they did just `.Sort()` (the first method in that link). So I guess mine should work

Comment: @nawfal: There had to be some other reason for the exception, the `StringNum` class has no relation to the `String` class, so if you don't use it in the `Sort` call it won't change the result at all. In the example that you are reading they have a `List<Customer>` where the `Customer` class implements `IComparable<Customer>`, so the `Sort` method will use that without specifying a comparison in the call. That doesn't work with a `List<String>` as you can't change the implementation of the `String` class.

Comment: @Guffa ya you are right. I'm going for your piece of code `items.Sort(delegate(string a, string b){ return new StringNum(a).CompareTo(new StringNum(b)); });` . Thanks for that ! :)

Comment: @JoshG: Yes, that is true. However, it's sometimes hard to determine when a number actually is negative. For example, in a string like `"abc-45-def"`, the first dash could either be a separator or indicating a negative number.

Comment: @Guffa: nice work, but sorting these two lists (which have the same elements), produces different results: {"b10", "b", "a", "a10"}, {"a10","a","b","b10"}. Is it a bug or a feature ;) ?

Comment: @RazvanSocol: That's a bug, of course. :) Thanks for spotting it. I overlooked how different length strings should be sorted. I fixed the code in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

The following code based on Joey's suggestion works for me (extension method to string[]):

```
public static void SortLogical(this string[] files)
{
    Array.Sort<string>(files, new Comparison<string>(StrCmpLogicalW));
}

[DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling=true)]
private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(String x, String y);
```

Comment: This is great, but where do u get the shlwapi.dll? moreover it seems it wont work in windows7

Comment: +1: Cutting and pasting this worked perfectly for me, and on Windows-7 too.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to pad the numeric portion like so:

```
file_00001
file_00002
file_00010
file_00011
```

etc.

But this reles on knowing the maximum value the numeric portion can take.

Comment: Thanks. How do you pad the numbers in c#? Do you mean parsing and inserting the number into the string?

Comment: I think Mitch means: try not to start with that data in the first place... change your input to **avoid** the need to process it.

Comment: Thanks I see. Unfortunately I will not have control over the filenames (on user machines) :)

Answer (score 2):

I have used the following approach in a project a while ago. It's not particularly efficient, but if the number of items to sort is not huge it performed well enough for that use. What it does is that it splits up the strings to compare into arrays on the `'_'` character, and then compares each element of the arrays. An attempt is made to parse the last element as an int, and make a numeric comparison there.

It also has an early exit if the input strings would contain a different number of elements (so if you compare "file_nbr_1" to "file_23", it will not go into comparing each part of the strings, but rather just to a regular string comparison on the full strings):

```
char[] splitChars = new char[] { '_' };
string[] strings = new[] {
    "file_1",
    "file_8",
    "file_11",
    "file_2"
};

Array.Sort(strings, delegate(string x, string y)
{
    // split the strings into arrays on each '_' character
    string[] xValues = x.Split(splitChars);
    string[] yValues = y.Split(splitChars);

    // if the arrays are of different lengths, just 
    //make a regular string comparison on the full values
    if (xValues.Length != yValues.Length)
    {
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }

    // So, the arrays are of equal length, compare each element
    for (int i = 0; i < xValues.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == xValues.Length - 1)
        {
            // we are looking at the last element of the arrays

            // first, try to parse the values as ints
            int xInt = 0;
            int yInt = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(xValues[i], out xInt) 
                && int.TryParse(yValues[i], out yInt))
            {
                // if parsing the values as ints was successful 
                // for both values, make a numeric comparison 
                // and return the result
                return xInt.CompareTo(yInt);
            }
        }

        if (string.Compare(xValues[i], yValues[i], 
            StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return x.CompareTo(y);

});
```